# Gradle. Running tests in parallel from one Class

Tags: gradle

Using Java 11, Gradle 6.5.1

In the build.gradle there is an option:

```
maxParallelForks = 8
```

I have two classes, first has 2 tests and second has 30 tests.
When I run tests using Gradle it runs only in 2 threads:

```
./gradlew clean test
```

One thread - tests for the first class, second thread - tests for the second class.

But, how to make Gradle to execute all tests in parallel?
So tests from the same class could be run in parallel in 8 threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JUnit 5, you can do this using JUnit's [parallel execution](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) instead of Gradle's. Note that this will be within the same JVM (I believe Gradle's `maxParallelForks` uses separate JVMs).

E.g. in your Gradle script:

```
test {
    ...... (your existing stuff here)
    systemProperties = [
        'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled': 'true'
        'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default': 'concurrent'
    ]
}
```

Different test frameworks may have equivalents.

---

Other than that, a workaround might be to split your tests into a separate class per test case. You can use things like test class inheritance to avoid duplication with this.

If you have more than the 2 test classes you've mentioned here, you'd only need to split up the few longest running classes to get most of the benefit.